# Android studio emulator camera not working properly

Tags: android-studio

I have a little problem in android studio emulator. I can use it for others activities, but when I turn on camera it goes to "not responding" mode. 
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be because you didnt choose options to use camera while creating your AVD.

I suggest you to use **genymotion emulator** , with this you can execute your code way faster and also you can choose from so many virtual devices.

Download genymotion from [here](https://www.genymotion.com).

Also its camera works very fine.
Its android plugin for android studio will help you run it on a single click.

Comment: Thank you! I installed genymotion, and it is much faster.

Comment: Great ! Happy to help.